# Why does replacing a string in files with find and exec sed not work

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, find, sed

Goal is to replace all references to my old email. I tried

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/old\@email.com/new\@email.com/g' {} \;
```

Yet it just shows nothing. It goes on and on and nothing happens.

I tried

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/old\@email.com/new\@email.com/g' {} \; | pv
```

Yet all I see is

```
0B 1:03:01 [   0B/s] [<=>                                                 ]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: When you use `sed -i`, replacements are done in-place. So no output is shown, but the file gets modified. Check the files and see if they changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i
```

It wouldn't show the replacements done on the file, You have to manually check them or just `grep 'new\@email.com'`

If you are on an ubuntu machine use:

```
sed -i.bak
```